# Display kable table in line with text -- Sweave Rnw file

Tags: dataframe, pdf-generation, knitr, sweave, kable

I have an Rnw file with a table using the `kable` command. I want the table to be displayed in line with the text that it follows. How can I stop the table from being displayed at the top of the page? This is the Rnw code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Here is my data, which is supposed to be below this sentence.
\\
\begin{abstract}
<<>>=
a <- 1; b <-2; c <-3; d <- 4
df.mse <- data.frame(row.names = c("Normal model", "Laplace model"))
df.mse["Normal model", "Normal MLE"] <- a
df.mse["Normal model", "Laplace MLE"] <- b
df.mse["Laplace model", "Normal MLE"] <- c
df.mse["Laplace model", "Laplace MLE"] <-d
library(knitr)
kable(df.mse, caption="approximate MSE for each model/estimator combination")
@
\end{abstract}


\end{document}
```

I'd prefer for the solution to not involve changing the actual Tex file, as I'd like to carry on working on the Sweave file without worrying about overriding the solution. I know you can use the float package in LaTeX but I'm not sure how to do that in the context of a Sweave file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't include a caption in the call to `kable`.  Then it will just output a `tabular` environment without wrapping it in a `table` float.  If the caption is not required, that simply means leaving out the `caption` argument in your call to `kable`.

If you do want a caption, but want the table placed inline, you need to start your table with `\begin{table}[h]`.  You can put that in the `Rnw` file like this:

```
<<>>=
a <- 1; b <-2; c <-3; d <- 4
df.mse <- data.frame(row.names = c("Normal model", "Laplace model"))
df.mse["Normal model", "Normal MLE"] <- a
df.mse["Normal model", "Laplace MLE"] <- b
df.mse["Laplace model", "Normal MLE"] <- c
df.mse["Laplace model", "Laplace MLE"] <-d
library(knitr)
@
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{This is the caption.}
<<echo=FALSE>>=
kable(df.mse)
@
\end{table}
```